# Ajuda com Array Multi

Tags: php, mysql, array

Olá alguém pode me ajudar como criar uma lista com php esse tipo de array.
Os dados vem de duas tabelas, Categorias e Produtos.

estou usando MySQL para buscar os dados das duas tabelas.

Minhas tabelas:

Categorias => id, nome

Produtos => id, id_categoria, nome, valor

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Pizzas",
        "lista": [
            {
                "NOME": "Pizza Pequena",
                "VALOR": "30"
            },
            {
                "NOME": "Pizza Media",
                "VALOR": "30"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Bebidas",
        "lista": [
            {
                "NOME": "Refri",
                "VALOR": "3"
            },
            {
               "NOME": "Suco",
                "VALOR": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Já tentei mais só consigo listar as categorias.

Comment: Você não tá conseguindo pegar os valores dentro de "lista"?

Comment: na verdade é criar a lista, preciso exibir ela dessa forma na web. mais não consigo, pois é um meio q uma api, para eu recuperar via axios no react native

Comment: Ixi, então terá que colocar na pergunta os códigos que você está usando, a query, a estrutura da tabela etc. para que se possa saber como montar o json.

Comment: Tem que informar tb que tipo de banco está usando (se é MySQL) e a linguagem (se é PHP)

Comment: ajustei minha pergunta,.

Comment: Só acho que a pizza média deveria custar mais caro que a pequena, mas... ;P

Comment: rsrs, tb. :p valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PHP:

```
 <?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste");

    $meuArray = array();
    //Add dados:
    $i = 0;
    if ($sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Categorias")){
        while ($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()){
    //Posição 0
            $id = $row['id'];
        array_push($meuArray, array(
            "id"=> $row['id'],
            "nome" => $row['nome']));


        if ($st = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `Produtos` WHERE `id_categoria` = '$id'")){
            while ($row2 = $st->fetch_assoc()){

                array_push($meuArray[$i], array("Nome"=> $row2['nome'],
                                          "Valor" => $row2['valor']));

            }
        }

        $i++;
        }
    }

    //Aqui já pegamos todos os campos;
    print_r($meuArray);
```

Resposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi mal pela demora, tava resolvendo uns negócios aqui primeira kkkkk

Comment: A partir daí você faz sua lógica e implementa a sua necessidade aí

Comment: minha array não está montada. é justamente isso que não sei como juntar as duas tabelas em uma só!

Comment: @CamilaF você quer buscar os dados do mysqli e com eles montar o array?

Comment: sim! isso, eu já tentei só consigo pegar as categorias.

Comment: @CamilaF basta fazer a query e usar um while pra ir preenchendo os campos do array com os dados que vem do servidor. Só um momento, dx eu fazer um exemplo aqui

Comment: @CamilaF, veja se é isso que você queria, e dscp pela demora, tava meio ocupado aqui :3

Comment: Nossa parece que vc copiou o meu bando de dados, rsrs :p era isso mesmo!! obrigada!!! s2

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `INNER JOIN` para fazer o SELECT. Assim:

```
SELECT * FROM categoria INNER JOIN produtos WHERE categoria.id = produtos.id_categoria ORDER BY categoria.nome
```

Desta forma você irá conseguir selecionar os produtos através da categoria. Depois você implementa da melhor maneira, exemplo:

```
 $query = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM categoria INNER JOIN produtos WHERE categoria.id = produtos.id_categoria ORDER BY categoria.nome");

 $bebidas = array();
 $pizzas = array();

 $produtos = array();

  while($prods = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    if(in_array($prods[1], $produtos)){
        $produtos[$prods[1]][] = array($prods['nome'], $prods['valor']);
    } else {
        $produtos[] = $prods[1];
        $produtos[$prods[1]][] = array($prods['nome'], $prods['valor']);
    }
  }

  print_r($produtos);
```

Comment: Obrigada pela força! vou da uma olhada nesse seu!

Comment: tranquilo! =) @CamilaF o legal de usar o inner join é que você fará apenas uma conexão com o banco de dados. Isso gera mais otimização ao servidor.

Comment: humm, já tinha ouvido falar, mais nunca usei. vou fazer ums testes!